# How to convert Fixnum to Integer in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, integer, fixnum

I am trying to get Integers, but i am getting 'Fixnum' values.

For Eg:

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
arr.each do |a|
m = a.to_i
m.class.name

Result
=> Fixnum
```

According to the above example, how can i get Integer values?
Fixnum is a Integer only but while implementing one plugin, it will through an error like 'Please enter only integer'.

Comment: You might want to raise a question about the plugin then. As it stands, you think you know the problem, and have asked for a solution to solve it the way you think it's broken; but it's likely that the *real* issue that's generating those errors is something else (like, maybe one of the elements in the array that goes to the plugin isn't a number like you think it is :-)

Answer (score 14):

In Ruby integers are either of the class `Fixnum` or `Bignum` for bigger numbers. Both of them   inherit from the `Integer` class.

So you already got an integer, no need to convert it further.

```
1.class #=> Fixnum
1.class.superclass #=> Integer
```

---

To convert the array elements to integers you would do this:

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
arr.map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @ShruthiRamesh Can you give some more context?

Comment: @ShruthiRamesh, `But i am getting an error like 'Please enter only integer'`, then the plugin you said you are using is wrong.

Comment: @ShruthiRamesh it sounds like the plugin wants an integer, you're passing in an array

Answer (score 0):

`Fixnum` is the ruby class for standard integers.

Well to be specific, the Integer class covers both `Fixnum`s and `Bignum`s, but in all honesty there's nothing to done here.

Answer (score 0):

All `Fixnum`(s) are already `Integer`. Here is some sample:

```
"12".to_i.class
#=> Fixnum
"12".to_i.integer?
#=> true
"12".to_i.to_int
#=> 12
```

The above all is possible as-

```
"12".to_i.class.superclass
#=> Integer
```